# How to export all Yahoo emails using PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what the best way to export about 90K emails off of a Yahoo account? The way it stands now, I believe that every email would need to be extracted one by one. I'd like to write a program to do this for me. Can someone give me any ideas as to the best way to so this?

What I am after are the sender email addresses (that are not already in my "contacts") so that I can use them in a list manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using POP3 access to retrieve your mail. IMAP will be ideal, but not sure if all Yahoo accounts have IMAP access.

You probably do not need to do it programmatically if you just want to archive them.

E.g.: [How do I archive messages?](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/mailplus/pop/poparchive-02.html;_ylt=AsLbS1uYkgCc5TuEBNTQLGMKzyN4)

Comment: Hi OKW, I'm going to look into this as well now. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: Unless I'm completely missing something in what I just read, I should be able to POP the messages to OExpress and then export the fields that I need from there. Whew!  Thanks OKW!

Comment: @Jim: Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar tasks with **gmail** using their IMAP interface and PHP's IMAP package.

Here is the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

I believe Yahoo Mail also supports IMAP...

Answer (score 0):

I believe Yahoo mail supports IMAP, which would be by far the best way to access the sender name for all your emails. It also looks like PHP has an [imap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) module which will make this easier.

All you have to do is [plug the pieces together](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/04/9856634.aspx). :)

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks. You are also on board with the same solution as Gahooa. I'm going to look into this now.